# php not running sqlldr

Tags: php, linux, sql-loader

I have a problem here whereby when i run sqlldr command using PHP, it does not seem to work. 
but when i run the exact same command in the linux command line, it works perfectly.

It does not give me any error when running in PHP. The following is the sample code that i was using :-

$sqlldr_cmd = "sqlldr userid=jconvey/natsoft@localhost/NATSOFT, control=/appvol/www/import/STG_HUB_CUST.ctl, errors=5000, bad=/appvol/www/import/STG_HUB_CUST.bad, log=/appvol/www/import/STG_HUB_CUST.log, discard=/appvol/www/import/STG_HUB_CUST.dsc";

system($sqlldr_cmd);

would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction how to debug this ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what's the return value or the result of system()?

try using absolute path of the command.